# Saving two strings to one text file without disrupting each other

Tags: java, android, string, file, save

I want to save two strings to one text file at the same time. One of the strings constantly inputs data, while the other only writes data when a button is clicked. However, when I click the button to add the value from there to the txt file, it writes, but it deletes all data from the other string before it. After, the other string goes back to writing as normal.

Here is the code for the two strings printing to the file:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    EditText bodyText;
                    bodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETName);
                    String name = bodyText.getText().toString();

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html")));
                    out.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + name
                            + "</h3><br>");
                    // new arraylist
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

        });

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html", true)));
            writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + text
                    + "</h3><br>");

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddNametoFile);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    EditText bodyText;
                    bodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETName);
                    String name = bodyText.getText().toString();

                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html", true)));
                    out.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + name
                            + "</h3><br>");

                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

        });

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html", true)));
            writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + text
                    + "</h3><br>");
            // new arraylist
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // put notification here later!!!
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

Basically, I wanted two strings to save to one file, then co-existing in the file (no overwrites etc..). My first code sample placed in one string, then overwrote it with the other. The new code now writes the two strings the same, so neither overwrite each other.